# javascript button not working in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am currently new to web development. I have overlooked this code until my head hurts. Does anybody see why clicking on the login button does nothing?

```
    function validate()
{
  if( validateEmail(document.myForm.login.value)!==true )
  {
    alert( "Please provide your valide email address!" );
    document.myForm.login.focus() ;
    return false;
  }

  if(form.password.value.length < 6) {
    alert("Error: Password must contain at least six characters!");
    form.password.focus();
    return false;
  }
  if(form.password.value == form.login.value) {
    alert("Error: Password must be different from Username!");
    form.password.focus();
    return false;
  }
  re = /[0-9]/;
  if(!re.test(form.password.value)) {
    alert("Error: password must contain at least one number (0-9)!");
    form.password.focus();
    return false;
  }
  re = /[a-z]/;
  if(!re.test(form.password.value)) {
    alert("Error: password must contain at least one lowercase letter (a-z)!");
    form.password.focus();
    return false;
  }
  re = /[A-Z]/;
  if(!re.test(form.password.value)) {
    alert("Error: password must contain at least one uppercase letter (A-Z)!");
    form.password.focus();
    return false;
  }
  else {
    alert("Error: Please check that you've entered and confirmed your password!");
    form.password.focus();
    return false;
  }
  return true; 
}

function validateEmail(email) {   
  var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
  return re.test(email);
}


var attempt = 3; // Variable to count number of attempts.
// Below function Executes on click of login button.
function doLogin(){
  if(validate()){
    var username = document.getElementById("login").value;
    var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
    if ( username == "admin@website.co.za" && password == "Password1"){
      alert ("Login successfully");
      window.location = "session.php"; // Redirecting to other page.
      return false;
    }
    else{
      attempt--;// Decrementing by one.
      alert("You have left "+attempt+" attempt;");
      // Disabling fields after 3 attempts.
      if( attempt === 0){
        document.getElementById("login").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("password").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("submit").disabled = true;
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

^^ javascript

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles\login_Style.css">
    <title>Log In</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="login">
        <h1>Login</h1>
        <form name="myForm" method="post" action="">
          <p>
            <input type="text" name="login" value="" placeholder="Email Address">
          </p>
          <p>
            <input type="password" name="password" value="" placeholder="Password">
          </p>
          <p class="submit">
            <button type="button" name="commit" value="Login" onclick="doLogin()">Login</button>
          </p>

          <p class="submit">
            <button type="button" name="back" value="back" onclick="document.location.href='home-page.html';">Back To Home Page</button>
          </p>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
<script></script>
</body>
</html>
```

^^ html button.Please note that the script is located just above body closing.

Comment: validate should be a method I guess. Or is that a global variable?

Comment: validate is a function. returns false on any error

Comment: what is 'validate' a boolean or a function returning one... its undefined. Mention it.

Comment: @RenierSwart please share the code of your `validate`function.

Comment: @chsdk Check scenario

Comment: @RenierSwart So in the beginning you were using `document.myForm` then you use `form.` where `form` is `undefined`, just replace all `form` occurences with `document.myForm`.

Comment: Managed to get past the errors in validation.. New error is at var username = document.getElementById("login").value; saying Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null

Comment: @RenierSwart that's because the login input doesn't have an `id`|  attribute it's `name="login"` instead, so simply use `document.myForm.login.value` instead of `document.getElementById("login").value`, this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to copy and paste this and you should be closer to solving your problem. I have included some comments in the code to help you understand what I did.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!--You need to reference these scripts to actually use any validation.-->
    <script src="lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <!--End Script reference-->
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles\login_Style.css">
    <title>Log In</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        function validate() {
            if (validateEmail(document.myForm.login.value) !== true) {
                alert("Please provide your valid email address!");
                document.myForm.login.focus();
                return false;
            }

            if (myForm.password.value.length < 6) {
                alert("Error: Password must contain at least six characters!");
                form.password.focus();
                return false;
            }
            if (myForm.password.value == myForm.login.value) {
                alert("Error: Password must be different from Username!");
                form.password.focus();
                return false;
            }
            re = /[0-9]/;
            if (!re.test(myForm.password.value)) {
                alert("Error: password must contain at least one number (0-9)!");
                form.password.focus();
                return false;
            }
            re = /[a-z]/;
            if (!re.test(myForm.password.value)) {
                alert("Error: password must contain at least one lowercase letter (a-z)!");
                form.password.focus();
                return false;
            }
            re = /[A-Z]/;
            if (!re.test(myForm.password.value)) {
                alert("Error: password must contain at least one uppercase letter (A-Z)!");
                form.password.focus();
                return false;
            }
            //Your else function was returning false therefore when you did actually validate you would always get false and never actually validate
            else {
                return true;
            }
        }

        function validateEmail(email) {
            var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
            return re.test(email);
        }


        var attempt = 3; // Variable to count number of attempts.
        // Below function Executes on click of login button.
        function doLogin() {
            if (validate()) {
                var username = document.getElementById("login").value;
                var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
                if (username == "admin@website.co.za" && password == "Password1") {
                    alert("Login successfully");
                    window.location = "session.php"; // Redirecting to other page.
                    return false;
                }
                else {
                    attempt--;// Decrementing by one.
                    alert("You have left " + attempt + " attempt;");
                    // Disabling fields after 3 attempts.
                    if (attempt === 0) {
                        document.getElementById("login").disabled = true;
                        document.getElementById("password").disabled = true;
                        document.getElementById("submit").disabled = true;
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    </script>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="login">
            <h1>Login</h1>
            <!--onsubmit it will call the function doLogin() and the action attribute will redirect to session.php-->
            <form name="myForm" method="post" onsubmit="doLogin()" action="session.php">
                <p>
                    <!--Use Id to tag the elements that are getElementById-->
                    <input type="text" name="login" id="login" placeholder="Email Address">
                </p>
                <p>
                    <!--Use Id to tag the elements that are getElementById-->
                    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password">
                </p>
                <p class="submit">
                    <!--Use Id to tag the elements that are getElementById-->
                    <!--Also the button type should be submit and id also submit-->
                    <button type="submit" name="commit" id="submit">Login</button>
                </p>

                <p class="submit">
                    <!--This is how I would do the back to home page button. It still should appear as a button-->
                    <a type="button" href="http://yoursite.com/home-page.html">Back To Home Page</a>
                </p>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I updated this some more. The validation is only going to work with your email that you have defined in your do login function. Also if this answered your concerns could you please mark this as the answer. Thanks and good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Since validate is a function you should use like this,

```
 function doLogin(){
      if(validate()){
```

Currently you are using it as a variable.

I have edited the code inside the fiddle. See this.
[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/atg5m6ym/3478/)

Comment: @Anup, It may not create an `error`.. `validate` will return `function-definition`.. Correct me If I am wrong...

Comment: login.html:17 Uncaught ReferenceError: doLogin is not definedonclick is the new error.....function doLogin(){
  if(validate()){

Comment: @RayonDabre didnt know that. thanks for the information.. :)

Comment: @AnoopJoshi . I Placed it in the head tag.. Error is now : login.html:17 Uncaught ReferenceError: form is not defined

Comment: @RenierSwart I dont see any 'form'  in your code. It might be in the validation. Then include the code for validation in question.

Comment: if you are using fiddle, place the javascript in script tag before html and then debug.. ..

Comment: @AnoopJoshi I still get login.html:45 Uncaught ReferenceError: form is not definedvalidate @ login.html:45doLogin @ login.html:84onclick @ login.html:21 when running in xamp.. Copy and pasted your html code

Answer (score -1):

Try below updated HTML code

```
<p class="submit"><button type="button" name="commit" value="Login" onclick="javascript:doLogin()">Login</button></p>
```

and make sure `validate` variable in the `doLogin` function have valid value like `true/false`

Comment: validate returns only true or false (true by default onless error is detected) . Gives error login.html:45 Uncaught ReferenceError: form is not definedvalidate @ login.html:45doLogin @ login.html:84onclick @ login.html:21

Comment: did you defined the `validate()` function. if yes please share same function